# Repeating & Incrementing Dates up to a given number of week in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A1 = 6-Dec
B1 = 2

**Goal:** Repeat all the dates 7 times starting from 6-Dec (Value in 'A1') up to 2 weeks (Value in 'B1')

**Formula Used :**

`=ArrayFormula(FLATTEN( split( REPT(SEQUENCE(7,1,A1,1)+SEQUENCE(1,B1,0,7)&"$",8),"$")))`

**Expected Result :**
Two columns for two weeks. Each date of the week to be repeated 8 times.[image]

**Actual Result :**
Only 1st week is repeated[image]

Please help me in correcting the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1+TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(B1,7*8,0)/8))
```

- `A1:` Date
- `B1`: Weeks
- `SEQUENCE`/`TRANSPOSE` to create a sequence of numbers increasing in the vertical direction
- `/8` Divide by `8` to create 8 fractional numbers for the same number.
- Add the fractional numbers to the date `A1` to create a date sequence repeated 8 times
- `FLOOR`[optional] the fractional numbers, if exact dates are needed without time difference.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(FLATTEN(TEXT(SEQUENCE(7, 1, A1), SEQUENCE(1, 8,,))), 
 SEQUENCE(1, B1,,))+SEQUENCE(1, B1,, 7))
```

[image]